# System.ObjectDisposedException in TCP sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Here is my server:

```
class Server
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5004);
            listener.Start();
            TcpClient client;
            while (true)
            {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("client connected");
                    break;
                }

            }


            NetworkStream sr = client.GetStream();
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] message = new byte[1024];
                sr.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                sr.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
```

and here is my client:

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Insert server address");
            string server = Console.ReadLine();
            if (server == "")
            {
                server = "192.168.1.2";
            }
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(server), 5004);

            NetworkStream sw = client.GetStream();
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
                sw.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
                sw.Close();
            }

        }

    }
```

When I run my server and the client first everything works and a "client connected" message appears. The problem is when I am trying to send a message from client to the server, a `System.ObjectDisposedException` is raised at the server in the `sr.Read(message, 0, message.Length);` line. Any idea how can I solved it or what is the cause?

Comment: You're closing the stream in the loop - what would you expect the second iteration of the loop to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the stream in the while loop, for both client and server. Move the `Close` below outside of the loop, or better still, make use of fact that [`Close` calls Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which allows you to use the `IDisposable` interface features like `using`:

```
using (NetworkStream sw = client.GetStream())
{
     while (true)
     {
         byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
         sw.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
         // Todo : Implement some kind of termination to the loop
     }
     sw.Flush();
 }
```